# webrtc is working on all browsers but not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

before anything ! i have checked all answers in similar questions and the answers wasn't usefull and old .
i have tried to use webrtc on firefox but it did not work ! and no error was givin !

this code work on all browsers but firefox

this is my code

```
let configuration = {

        "iceServers":[{
            'url':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        }]

};


io.on("signaling_message",(data)=>{

    //displayMessage(data.message);
    if(!rtcPeerConn){
       startSignaling();
     }

     if(data.type!="user_here"){
         let message  = JSON.parse(data.message);
         if(message.sdp){
             rtcPeerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp),()=>{
                 if(rtcPeerConn.remoteDescription.type=="offer"){
                     rtcPeerConn.createAnswer(sendLocalDesc,logerror)
                 }
             })
         }else{

            rtcPeerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
         }
     }

})

function startSignaling(){
    displayMessage("start signaling...");
  rtcPeerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
 //send ice candidate to other peer
        rtcPeerConn.onicecandidate  = function(evt){
            if(evt.candidate){
                io.emit("signal",{"type":"ice candidate","message":JSON.stringify({'candidate':evt.candidate}),room:signal_room})
                displayMessage("completed that ice candidate");
            }
        }
rtcPeerConn.onnegotiationneeded = function(){
    displayMessage("on negotiationnneded");
    rtcPeerConn.createOffer(sendLocalDesc,logerror);

}
rtcPeerConn.onaddstream = (evt,err)=>{
    displayMessage("creating  the other stream");
    if(err){
        displayMessage(err)
    }
    success2(evt.stream);
}

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:true}).then(stream=>{
             success(stream);
             rtcPeerConn.addStream(stream);
        }).catch(err=>{
             logerror(err);
            });

}


function sendLocalDesc(desc){

rtcPeerConn.setLocalDescription(desc,()=>{
displayMessage("set local description");
io.emit("signal",{type:"SDP",message:JSON.stringify({'sdp':rtcPeerConn.localDescription}),room:signal_room})


},logerror);

}


     function success(stream){
        if ("srcObject" in video) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        } else {
        // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }

        video.play();
        }




        function success2(stream){
        if ("srcObject" in video2) {
        video2.srcObject = stream;
        } else {
        // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
        video2.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }


        video2.play();
        }
```

is there anything wrong with my code?

another question , can i use google stun iceservers on production ? are they reliable?

**EDIT**

the firefox stuck at this script

```
  rtcPeerConn.onicecandidate  = function(evt){
            if(evt.candidate){
                io.emit("signal",{"type":"ice candidate","message":JSON.stringify({'candidate':evt.candidate}),room:signal_room})
                displayMessage("completed that ice candidate");
            }
        }
```

it keeps displaying this message (completed that ice candidate) like a loop

Answer (score 1):

Have you applied [webrtc-adapter?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter)

And google stun server is not proper on production.

Because if your clients are located behind NAT or firewall, P2P connection is impossible.

If P2P Connection failed in WebRTC, you have to ready TURN server for relay.

for example, you can use [coTURN](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)

Comment: thank you, but i didn't feel any changes after importing adapter. can you check please the (edit) part? the firefox browser stucks on (rtcPeerConn.onicecandidate)

Comment: maybe it's a clue

Comment: i have another question, how to use adapter? should i just include it ? i didn't find any documentation to use  methods

Comment: adapter is shim. what you need to do is just insert it before your script.
like this:
<script src="adapter.js"></script>
<script src="your_script.js"></script>

Comment: and I think maybe your configuration is wrong. could you test after fix it?
>> { iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }]
not 'url', but 'urls'. url property is obsolete

Comment: Even it didn't work after fix configuration, please check [onicegatheringstatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicegatheringstatechange) also. @MohamadAlasly